# Using an updated variable inside renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

I was having problems with using variables inside renderUI and after looking around, it seems like the problem is that it doesn't read a variable like normal, so I'm looking for solutions

lets say I have a variable called modelname

in the renderUI, if a radio button was selected, it will display several different pages depending on another radio button, but each one will have multiple downloadLinks.

What I would like is some way to set modelname to something for each combination, so that I can make a call to downloadHandler and use that modelname to access the right file.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you post a code and produce a reproducible examples. Without looking at the code, I can only guess the the problem pertains to not addressing objects correctly, as you would have when following guidance in [an article on scoping rules in Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html). I would suggest that you define your variables in `global.R` as it usually makes Shiny apps less messy.

Comment: its kind of tough because its a big app, maybe I'm explaining it poorly but I don't think that's it. Basically, I define a variable as "a". I want to change it to "b". Doing that outside renderUI works, but inside doesn't

Comment: @KingOfKong `renderUI` makes *a reactive version of a function that generates HTML using the Shiny UI library*, without seeing the code, I can only guess that your variables is not in the global environment. I'm wondering whether making use of the *[event handler](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/shiny/man/observeEvent.html)* could be a solution. You could have your *event handler* executing the desired function upon some interaction with the app.